# getting null ID to back-end through Url in rest controller

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest

I am getting ID Null to back-end which is parameter passing from front-end

```
    this.overAllSummery = function(offset,limit,search,colName,order,id){

    var url = 'api/dashboard/summary/'

        if(offset!= undefined){
            url=(url.indexOf("?") > -1)?url+"&offset="+offset:url+"?offset="+offset;
        }
        if(limit != undefined){
            url=(url.indexOf("?") > -1)?url+"&limit="+limit:url+"?limit="+limit;
        }
        if(search!=undefined && search!=""){
            url=(url.indexOf("?") > -1)?url+"&search="+search:url+"?search="+search;
        }
        if(colName != undefined){
            url=(url.indexOf("?") > -1)?url+"&colName="+colName:url+"?colName="+colName;
        }
        if(order != undefined){
            url=(url.indexOf("?") > -1)?url+"&order="+order:url+"?order="+order;

        }
        if(id != undefined){
            url=(url.indexOf("?") > -1)?url+"&id ="+id:url+"?id ="+id;
        }
        alert(id);
        var promise = $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : url,
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            },
            cache : false
        }).then(function (response) {
            return response;
        });
        return promise;     
    };
```

Whole above is front-end service using AngularJS and passing URL to call back-end, As I am passing different parameters I am getting all those to back-end except ID, and based Id I have to fetch records from DB.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/summary", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
public ResponseEntity<List<OverAllSummery>> overAllSummery(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam(value="offset",required=false) Integer offset,@RequestParam(value="limit",required=false) Integer limit,
@RequestParam(value="search",required=false) String search,@RequestParam(value="colName",required=false) String colName,@RequestParam(value="order",required=false) String order,
@RequestParam(value="id",required=false) Long id){

try {

    return new ResponseEntity<List<OverAllSummery>>(DashbordService.overAllSummery(offset,limit,search,colName,order,id), HttpStatus.OK);
} catch (Exception exception) {
    logger.error("Error retriving all categories", exception);
    return new ResponseEntity<List<OverAllSummery>>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

Above is the rest controller I am using, call is passing to back-end to in debug mode but ID is coming null and I am getting 404 in front-end console.

[image]

Above you can see after adding URL in alert, where ID=1 but, after call going to back-end that id becoming null

[image]

you can see above that Id in API

Comment: Please add "Alert(url) " before making the call to Get call to Rest api to know what exactly is being passed, based on that we may figure out what is causing the issue and find the value that is being passed.

Comment: you can see question. I edited as you told after using alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check after removing that extra space from your URL.Urls should not have spaces in them.

[image: Remove this extra space]

Comment: absolutely correct, URL should not have spaces in between

Comment: Always post the necessary details so that we can help you solve your issue quicker:)@phanikumar

Answer (score 0):

`@RequestMapping(value = "dashboard/summary" ...)` you didn't add id as param in requestMapping

add {id} `@RequestMapping(value = "dashboard/summary/{id}" ...)`

api you call `dashboard/summary/1`

Comment: if I add ID in request mapping it will give  " No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/gdpr/api/dashboard/summary/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'  error and as you mentioned above If I pass as " /summary/1"  it will become hard coded Id

Comment: 1 is id you can pass anything

Comment: @phanikumar may be you accepting API is wrong. you create an api /summary/ where you called an api /dashboard/summary

Answer (score 0):

Error 404 in HTTP definitely means the server (back-end) doesn't know the url, you're trying to access. Internal Server Error, which is produced by the catch block is HTTP 500, thus back-end didn't produce the exception. So the first thing to check is which URL you're trying to access actually. By the way try to use'/api/dashboard/summary', instead of what is used now on the front-end.

Comment: URL and everything is correct, call is going to back-end  through debugging but, In back-end ID becoming null. Actually it should the value which I am passing through ID parameter

Comment: Then it's not 404. I propose to use (@RequestParam<String,String>parameters) in your handler method. It will show you which parameters you passed. For example if you're using 'id ' instead of 'id' it probably won't be mapped automatically.